# CORS errors after deployment to render, worked fine locally

Tags: javascript, http, https, cors

like the title says, here is my server file, I have tried every solution I could find on google yet I am still getting CORS errors. specifically `XHROPTIONShttps://slug-panel-api.onrender.com/login`

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = require('../../SlugAPI/Schemas/SlugSchemas')
const divisionSchema = require('../src/SlugSchemas/DivisionSchemas/DivisionSchema')
const subDivisionSchema = require('../src/SlugSchemas/DivisionSchemas/SubDivisionSchema')
const teamSchema = require('../src/SlugSchemas/DivisionSchemas/TeamSchema')
const divisionMemberSchema = require('../src/SlugSchemas/DivisionSchemas/DivisionMemberSchema')
let CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://slug-panel.onrender.com",
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://slug-panel.onrender.com",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    },
}));
mongoose.set("debug")

const usar_db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb:/<username>:<password>@slug-db:27017/usarAdmin?authSource=admin");


const User = usar_db.model('User', userSchema)
const Division = usar_db.model('Division', divisionSchema)
const SubDivision = usar_db.model('SubDivision', subDivisionSchema)
const Team = usar_db.model('Team', teamSchema)
const DivisionMember = usar_db.model('Division_Member', divisionMemberSchema)


function generateUserRegistrationKey(username, discord_id, rank, authentication_level) {
    let key = username + '/' + discord_id.toString() + '/' + rank + '/' + authentication_level
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(key, 'secret').toString()
    return ciphertext
}

function decryptUserRegistrationKey(key) {
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(key, 'secret')
    const originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
    return originalText
}

app.post('/login', bodyParser.json(), async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = req.body.username
    let pw = req.body.password
    pw = CryptoJS.SHA256(pw)
    let exists = await User.findOne({username: user})
    if (exists) {
        if (pw.toString() === exists['password']) {
            res.send({
                token: 'test123'
            })
        } else {
            res.send({
                error: 'passwordNotFound'
            })
        }
    } else {
        res.send({
            error: 'userNotFound'
        })
    }
});

app.post('/generate', bodyParser.json(), async function (req, res, next) {
    let username = req.body.username
    let discord_id = req.body.discord_id
    let rank = req.body.rank
    let authentication_level = req.body.authentication_level
    let exists = await User.exists({discord_id: discord_id})
    let regKey = generateUserRegistrationKey(username, discord_id, rank, authentication_level)
    const newUser = User({
        username: username,
        discord_id: discord_id,
        rank: rank,
        regKey: regKey,
        authentication_level: authentication_level,
    })
    if (!exists) {
        newUser.save()
            .then(r => console.log("User " + username + " added to db"))
        res.send({regKey: regKey})
    }
})

app.post('/register', bodyParser.json(), async function (req, res, next) {
    let key = req.body.regKey
    let pw = CryptoJS.SHA256(req.body.password).toString()
    let decryptedKey = decryptUserRegistrationKey(key).split('/')
    let exists = await User.find({regKey: key}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log('Result: ', docs)
            console.log(pw)
        }
    }).clone()
    if (!exists) {
        res.send({user: null})
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(exists))
    }

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({regKey: key}, { is_registered: true, password: pw, authentication_level: decryptedKey[decryptedKey.length - 1]})
})

app.post('/createDivision', bodyParser.json(),  async function (req, res, next) {
    let div_name = req.body.division_name
    let div_id = req.body.division_id
    let exists = await Division.findOne({division_name: div_name}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(docs)
        }
    }).clone()
    let idexists = await Division.findOne({division_id: div_id}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(docs)
        }
    }).clone()
    if (!exists || !idexists) {
        const newDivision = new Division({
            division_name: div_name,
            division_id: div_id
        })
        newDivision.save()
            .then(() => console.log('Division ' + div_name + ' has been added to the db'))
        res.send(JSON.stringify(newDivision))
    } else {
        res.send({errorcode: 420})
    }
})

app.post('/createSubDivision/:divid', bodyParser.json(), async function (req, res, next) {
    const division = req.params['divid']
    const sub_name = req.body.subdivision_name
    const sub_id = req.body.subdivision_id
    let exists = await Division.findOne({division_id: division}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(docs)
        }
    }).clone()
    if (exists) {
        let subdivid_exists = await Division.findOne({
            division_id: division,
            subdivisions: {
                $elemMatch: {subdivision_id: sub_id}
            }
        })
        let subdiv_exists = await Division.findOne({
            division_id: division,
            subdivisions: {
                $elemMatch: {subdivision_name: sub_name}
            }
        })
        if (!subdivid_exists || !subdiv_exists) {
            const subDiv = new SubDivision({
                subdivision_name: sub_name,
                subdivision_id: sub_id,
            })
            await Division.findOneAndUpdate({division_id: division}, { $push: {subdivisions: subDiv}})
            console.log('subdivision ' + sub_name + ' added to: ' + exists.division_name)
            res.send(JSON.stringify(subDiv))
        } else {
            res.send({division:'exists'})
        }
    }
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('API is running on ' + PORT));
```

Tried every solution I could find both on random google websites and on stackoverflow. as stated previously it worked fine on the development server hosted locally.

for reference, here is how I am using fetch throughout the frontend

```
async function loginUser(credentials) {
    return fetch('https://slugga-api.onrender.com/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    })
        .then(data => data.json())
}
```

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://slugga-api.onrender.com/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://slugga-api.onrender.com/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. asyncToGenerator.js:6:4
    Babel 6
    c Login.js:20
    React 11
    bind_applyFunctionN self-hosted:1683
    Wt self-hosted:1640
    React 3
    forEach self-hosted:4909
    React 2
    <anonymous> index.js:7
    <anonymous> index.js:17
    <anonymous> index.js:17
```

[image: OPTIONS response]

Comment: The preflight response appears to contain the required headers, but it has status code 404. One requirement for preflight to succeed is that the preflight response have some status code between 200 and 299. You need to figure out why that 404 is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing those CORS headers, both on the client side and on the server side. You should familiarise better with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and with the API of [Express.js's CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

### Client side

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is a *response* header; including it in a request makes no sense.

```
async function loginUser(credentials) {
    return fetch('https://slugga-api.onrender.com/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true' // incorrect
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    })
        .then(data => data.json())
}
```

### Server side

The `headers` property of your CORS config corresponds to *request* headers that you wish to allow, but what you've listed are *response* headers.

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://slug-panel.onrender.com",
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://slug-panel.onrender.com", // incorrect
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true // incorrect
    },
}));
```

Instead, you most likely want something like

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://slug-panel.onrender.com",
    headers: ["Content-Type"],
    credentials: true,
}));
```

Comment: Still has the same issue, made the changes, same POST being changed to OPTION

Comment: What you're observing is the preflight request. Please edit your question: add the CORS error message (as text) as well as a screenshot of the preflight request (the one using `OPTIONS`) including its headers.

Comment: I will get right on that when I get home from work! Thank you for your input :)

Comment: I have added the errors and a screenshot of the entire OPTIONS response

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by changing the CORS initialization in server.js

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors({
        origin: "https://slug-panel.onrender.com"
    }
))
app.options('*', cors())
```